# be careful of someone's health?

Tags: word-meaning

Does "be careful of" make sense in the following?

**Be careful of** John's health. He may have a heart attack anytime.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: **anytime** is a colloquialism there. **at any time** would be more formal.

Answer (score 5):

[Mindful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mindful) may be a better word to use in this case.

> **Be mindful of** John's health. He may have a heart attack anytime.

Comment: Can I use "Mind John's health"?

Comment: No, "to mind" and "to be mindful of" mean different things. "To mind someone's health" implies to me that you are actively taking care of them; "to be mindful of" implies simply that you're being careful not to do anything harmful.

Comment: @mamster - I don't know about that - [*mind the gap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_the_gap) means "Be careful of the gap", not "take care of the gap" - but I agree that "Mind John's health" sounds stilted.

Comment: How about "mind John's age"?

Answer (score 0):

> **Keep an eye on** John's health.

[*Keep an eye on*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep-an-eye-on):

> to look after; watch carefully